# Hidden scroll hides the bottom of span's text

Tags: html, css

In order to make my text to be automatically trimmed with three dotes (`...`) I've used this css and it work perfectly.

The only problem is that the scroll is now hides the bottom of my span's text:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <span>
        googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parentDiv { 
    position: relative;        
    width: 100%;
}

.parentDiv > span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;     
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this is the result, pay attention that the `g` is being cut at its bottom:
[image]

this is causing because the `overflow: hidden;`, if i change it to `overflow: auto`, we can see that the scroll is hiding the span's bottom text.

[image]

**How can i still represent the dotted text with no hiding of the bottom span's text?**

Comment: `.parentDiv { margin-bottom: 20px; }` or `.parentDiv { padding-bottom: 20px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to one of the comment, this does the trick:

```
.parentDiv > span {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding to '.parentDiv' padding-bottom of some percentage, maybe 5%, but see what working for you

```
 .parentDiv { 
     position: relative;        
     width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 5%;
 }
```